# A GET inside a GET

Tags: php, facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, get

The problem i'm facing right now is im getting a URL, like so:

```
www.example.com/example.php?url=www.google.com
```

now the problem is, if theres a get in my url, like so:

```
www.example.com/example.php?url=www.google.com?id=1
```

it doesn't actually cause a problem yet, but if theres two GET vars in the my URL, it doesn't know where the "and" goes, the first get or the second one, and basically just chooses the first, ex:

```
www.example.com/example.php?url=www.google.com?id=1&username=me
```

is there a workaround? I could recode a lot of things to have it as one get variable, but it'll involve a lot of work and  I wish i could have a solution!
thanks!

Heres my code:

```
$facebookapi=new facebook(array('appId'=>'*******','secret'=>'********','fileUpload'=>'false'));
$url='http://******.com/questions/view.php?id=884&username=robot';
$facebookapi->api('/me/******app:answer?question=' . urlencode($url),'POST');
```

Comment: Which language? PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: You need to encode the special characters e.g. `&`,`=`,`?` - note you will need to recursively do this, so if you have a query inside a query inside a query, you need to multi-encode

Comment: Try this --  <?php

$url = 'www.google.com?id=1';
echo 'www.example.com/example.php?url='.urldecode(urlencode($url)).'&username=me';  ?>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode the `url` parameter.

```
$url = 'www.google.com?id=1';
echo 'www.example.com/example.php?url='.urlencode($url).'&username=me';
```

***Edit:***
After seeing your posted code, it seems that you should use the third parameter for params.

```
$url='http://******.com/questions/view.php?id=884&username=robot';
$facebookapi->api('/me/******app:answer', 'POST', array('question' => $url));
```

Comment: except the facebook api doesn't work like that. So it fails. ill try it again.

Comment: @Robert What api are your using? Has facebook such api?

Comment: it gets the full URL now, but my result doesn't work. How strange. But it isn't your problem anymore. Thanks! And yes, it has this api. Its called Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

Well the function [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is perfect for this.

Once the url is encoded,
The first get variable will turn from this

`www.google.com?id=1&username=me`

to this

`www.google.com%3Fid%3D1&6username=me`

Your website will then appear as [www.example.com/example.php?url=www.google.com%3Fid%3D1%26username%3Dme]

Once PHP receives that variable you can decode it

`$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);`

Note: some versions of PHP do it automatically.